# Vertically align icon inside search bar

Tags: html, css

I know this question seems silly, so I want to apoligize in advance.

I have this input below:
[image] where everything seems fine until I add a label on top like below:

[image]

This is what I have at the moment:

```css
.inputWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    height: min-content;
    position: relative;
}    

.icon {
    height: 2.1rem;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    font-size: fontSizeBig;
    background: transparent;
    padding: .6rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='inputWrapper'>
    <input/>
    <button class='icon'>
        <icon/>
    </button>
</div>
```

The height here is not helping and I would like to make the icon always hotizontally aligned with the input, without worrying how many divs I can put on top.

Which is the best practice for this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: adjust top value

Comment: Where is the label ?

Comment: upload the proper code

Comment: As @XenioGracias mentioned please create a minimal, complete and verifable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I added a code snippet in your question based on the code you provided and it doesn't behave like you suggest in your question..

Comment: you can use `line-height`

Comment: You could add a bottom value for your icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting a wrapper around just the `<input/>` and the `<button class="icon"></button>` so that the relative position is not disturbed if you add a label outside of the wrapper:

```html
<div class='outerWrapper'>
    <label><!-- Will not disturb inputWrapper --></label>
    <div class='inputWrapper'>
        <input/>
        <button class='icon'>
            <icon/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this was the best solution for the issue.